# Heroku npm Build Error Logs Location

Tags: heroku, npm, heroku-cli

I've deployed my node web app to heroku.  Its built but failed to start.  Here's the first few lines of output:

```
2018-03-05T20:17:51.058817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: - Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-03-05T20:17:52.868249+00:00 app[web.1]: - npm ERR! missing script: start
2018-03-05T20:17:52.874771+00:00 app[web.1]: - 
2018-03-05T20:17:52.874973+00:00 app[web.1]: - npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-03-05T20:17:52.875068+00:00 app[web.1]: - npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-05T20_17_52_869Z-debug.log
```

The error log goes on, but I'm trying to located the log location:

/app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-05T20_17_52_869Z-debug.log

How do I get to this?